# SQL Query for amount of products sold within dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

**Fiddle Here**:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f85f4/1

I am trying to create an 'inventory demand' report essentially; what products were sold between X and Y and how much of them.

The closest I can get is this query, but this doesn't return the correct math.

Can someone please offer some guidance?

```
SELECT orders_products.op_products_name
     , orders_products.op_products_id
     , SUM(orders_products.op_products_qty) AS TotalSold 
  FROM orders_products
     , orders 
 WHERE orders.orders_date_purchased
   AND orders.orders_date_purchased BETWEEN '2012-11-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-10 00:00:00'
 GROUP 
    BY orders_products.op_products_id 
 ORDER 
    BY TotalSold DESC
```

The schema is available here:

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `orders`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `orders_ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `orders_date_purchased` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `orders_delivery_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `orders_delivery_company_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `orders_delivery_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `orders_delivery_city` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `orders_delivery_state` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `orders_delivery_zipcode` char(5) NOT NULL,
  `orders_delivery_phone` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `orders_delivery_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `orders_billing_name` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_billing_address` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_billing_city` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_billing_state` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_billing_zipcode` char(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_billing_phone` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_billing_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_users_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `orders_distributor_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_affiliate_ID` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_sales_tax` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `orders_discount_applied` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_ip_address` char(15) NOT NULL,
  `orders_shipping_method` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `orders_payment_method` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `orders_order_total` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `orders_shipping_cost` decimal(11,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_total_saved` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `orders_placed_by` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `notes` blob,
  `orders_inv_status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_date_modified` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `orders_process_status` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2379 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `orders`

INSERT INTO `orders` (`orders_ID`, `orders_date_purchased`, `orders_delivery_name`, `orders_delivery_company_name`, `orders_delivery_address`, `orders_delivery_city`, `orders_delivery_state`, `orders_delivery_zipcode`, `orders_delivery_phone`, `orders_delivery_email`, `orders_billing_name`, `orders_billing_address`, `orders_billing_city`, `orders_billing_state`, `orders_billing_zipcode`, `orders_billing_phone`, `orders_billing_email`, `orders_users_ID`, `orders_distributor_ID`, `orders_affiliate_ID`, `orders_sales_tax`, `orders_discount_applied`, `orders_ip_address`, `orders_shipping_method`, `orders_payment_method`, `orders_order_total`, `orders_shipping_cost`, `orders_total_saved`, `orders_placed_by`, `notes`, `orders_inv_status`, `orders_date_modified`, `orders_process_status`) VALUES
(1, '2012-11-05 19:58:12', 'John Smith', '', '123 Manatee Street', 'Navarre', 'FL', '32566', '8508675309', 'email@email.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 83, NULL, NULL, 0.06, NULL, '00.000.000.00', 'in_person_delivery', 9, 61.59, 0.00, 0.00, 0, NULL, 8, NULL, 3),
(2, '2012-11-06 01:05:20', 'Judy Richards', '', '456 Devmor Ct', 'Navarre', 'FL', '32566', '8508675309', 'email@email.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 87, NULL, NULL, 0.06, NULL, '00.000.000.00', 'in_person_delivery', 9, 158.97, 0.00, 0.00, 0, NULL, 8, NULL, 3),
(4, '2012-11-08 04:32:23', 'John Smith', '', '123 Manatee Street', 'Navarre', 'FL', '32578', '8508675309', 'email@email.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 92, NULL, NULL, 0.06, NULL, '00.000.000.00', 'in_person_delivery', 9, 52.99, NULL, 0.00, 0, NULL, 8, '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 3),
(5, '2012-11-09 00:11:54', 'Adam Davis', '', '4307 D134 Legendary Dr.', 'Navarre', 'FL', '32541', '8508675309', 'email@email.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 89, 84, 0, 0.06, NULL, '00.000.000.00', 'in_person_delivery', 9, 160.51, 0.00, 0.00, 0, NULL, 8, NULL, 3),
(6, '2012-11-09 21:14:25', 'Judy Sterling', '', '2310 Lexington Lane', 'Navarre', 'FL', '32566', '8508675309', 'email@email.com', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 87, NULL, NULL, 0.06, NULL, '00.000.000.00', 'in_person_delivery', 9, 158.97, 0.00, 0.00, 0, NULL, 8, NULL, 3);

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `orders_products`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders_products` (
  `orders_products_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `op_order_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `op_products_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `op_products_mfr_part_number` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `op_products_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `op_products_qty` bigint(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`orders_products_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5923 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `orders_products`

INSERT INTO `orders_products` (`orders_products_ID`, `op_order_id`, `op_products_id`, `op_products_mfr_part_number`, `op_products_name`, `op_products_qty`) VALUES
(1, 1, 491, 'CWP8489A001BA', 'X25', 1),
(2, 2, 2134, 'Professional Fee', 'Professional Fe', 3),
(3, 3, 473, 'CWPDR360', 'DR-360', 1),
(4, 4, 2134, 'Professional Fee', 'Professional Fe', 1),
(5, 5, 362, 'CWPDR360', 'DR-360', 1);

---

--

### -- Table structure for table `products`

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `products_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `products_brand` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `products_brand_type` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `products_mfr_part_number` varchar(65) NOT NULL,
  `products_common_name` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `products_msrp` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `products_price` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL,
  `products_description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `products_weight` decimal(11,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1.00',
  `products_length` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_width` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_height` decimal(3,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `products_tax_exempt` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`products_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=2558 ;

--

### -- Dumping data for table `products`

INSERT INTO `products` (`products_id`, `products_brand`, `products_brand_type`, `products_mfr_part_number`, `products_common_name`, `products_msrp`, `products_price`, `products_description`, `products_weight`, `products_length`, `products_width`, `products_height`, `products_tax_exempt`) VALUES
(1, 'HP', 'Original', '92298A ', '98A', 132.99, 131.66, 'Genuine HPÂ® LaserJet 98A Black Toner Cartridge (92298A) ', 4.20, 9.99, 6.14, 9.72, NULL),
(2, 'HP', 'Original', 'C3903A ', '03A', 112.99, 111.86, 'Genuine HPÂ® LaserJet 03A Black Toner Cartridge (C3903A) ', 3.00, 9.99, 4.80, 7.72, NULL),
(3, 'HP', 'Original', 'C3906A ', '06A', 87.99, 87.11, 'Genuine HP® LaserJet 06A Black Toner Cartridge (C3906A)', 2.13, 9.99, 5.16, 6.50, NULL),
(4, 'HP', 'Original', 'C3909A', '09A', 254.99, 252.44, 'Genuine HP® LaserJet 09A Black Toner Cartridge (C3909A)', 3.31, 9.99, 4.72, 8.07, NULL),
(5, 'HP', 'Original', 'C4092A ', '92A', 75.99, 75.23, 'Genuine HP® LaserJet 92A Black Toner Cartridge (C4092A) ', 2.20, 9.99, 5.16, 6.50, NULL);

Comment: Can you provide the desired result set?

Comment: BTW, your naming policy is nuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The major problem is that you need a `join` condition between `orders_products` and `orders`.  You have a `,` which is equivalent to `cross join`.  As a simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

In addition, the `where` clause was awkwardly phrased.  Here is a rewrite of your query that also uses table aliases for readability:

```
SELECT op.op_products_name, op.op_products_id, SUM(op.op_products_qty) AS TotalSold
FROM orders_products op JOIN
     orders o
     ON op.op_order_id = o.orders_id
WHERE o.orders_date_purchased BETWEEN '2012-11-05 00:00:00' AND '2012-11-10 00:00:00'
GROUP BY op.op_products_id
ORDER BY TotalSold DESC;
```